# Splitting up data from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Currently I have a table like shown in *T1* that I'd like to split up into individual *Person* table like *T2* and a *PersonClientLink* table like *T3*. Each relationship is stored as its own unique ID in T1. This makes duplicates of the same person and their clients which is making this difficult. I need to group the Persons from T1 into a single ID and basically turn it into T2 and create links for each relationship they have into T3. T3 Currently exists but is empty, I want to populate T3 based on the data in T1 first and then turn T1 into T2. Any advice would be appreciated :)

**T1 - Current mess**

| ID | Client_Id | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | Bob |
| 2 | 6 | Bob |
| 3 | 7 | Greg |
| 4 | 8 | Greg |

**T2 - Person**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob |
| 2 | Greg |

**T3 - PersonClientLink**

| ID | Person_Id | Client_Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 6 |
| 3 | 2 | 7 |
| 4 | 2 | 8 |

I'm honestly clueless no idea where to begin with this...

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to take data from T1 and make T2, then use the data from T1+T2 to make T3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create the T2 and T3 tables and populate them from T1.  I would then drop T1 afterwards.  The following is done with postgresql, but it should be the same.  A serial column in postgresql is the same as an identity column in sqlserver.

```
create table t2 (id serial primary key,
                 name varchar(32) not null);
create table t3 (id serial primary key, 
                 person_id integer not null, 
                 client_id integer not null);
```

Create a foreign key from t3.person_id to t2.id

Populate t2 and t3:

```
insert into t2 (name) (select distinct name from t1);
insert into t3 (person_id,client_id) (
    select t2.id,t1.client_id from t1,t2 where t2.name = t1.name);
```

Convert the join of the tables to ANSI style if sqlserver requires that.

The initial data (same as yours) and the results:

```
select * from t1;
 id | client_id | name
----+-----------+------
  1 |         5 | bob
  2 |         6 | bob
  3 |         7 | greg
  4 |         6 | greg
(4 rows)

select * from t2;
 id | name
----+------
  1 | bob
  2 | greg
(2 rows)

select * from t3;
 id | person_id | client_id
----+-----------+-----------
  1 |         1 |         6
  2 |         1 |         5
  3 |         2 |         6
  4 |         2 |         7
(4 rows)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I agree with this solution, here's the fiddle for SQL Server if needed that I was working on but @robert donnenberg beat me to it :) https://dbfiddle.uk/rlcfrmqV